# Replace "NBSP" Character using MS Access SQL

Tags: ms-access

How to identify the NBSP character which looks like an empty space and replace it in MS Access SQL?
This is the character after the colon:

When I go to this site https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php, it says the character is: U+A0

How do I replace U+A0 with nothing?

Like SELECT Replace([number], char(U+A0), "") AS ReplaceString;

Comment: I believe that non-breaking space is character code 160. So REPLACE([number], CHAR(160), "") as ReplaceString` may do the trick

Comment: @JNevill You are correct, it is Chr(160)!  Thank you!

Comment: `CHR()` I always get VBA and Access formulas and Excel formulas confused.

Answer (score 0):

@JNevill is correct!

In order to remove the NBSP character using MS Access SQL, use the below statement:

Replace([column_a], Chr(160), "") AS ReplaceString

I later needed to also remove carriage returns which can be done with char(13) and char(10) like this:

replace(replace([column_a], Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), "")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).